# Eliminar del diff en github datos sensibles

Tags: git, github

Quiero eliminar datos sensibles que sale en el diff cuando comparan los commits en github, por x razones puse un dato sensible en un campo ,y luego de cambiarlo y pushearlo , este dato sigue saliendo en el historial de commit como parte de un cambio en un commit, ¿como puedo solucionar este problema , sin borrar el commit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al ser un trozo de texto dentro de un fichero y no un fichero entero es algo más complicado pero puedes copiar el contenido del fichero y utilizar:  `git filter-branch` o [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

Pásate por [aquí](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) para más información.

Amplio la información:

Tienes que utilizar BFG Repo-Cleaner ya que es mas rápido y tiene más opciones que `git filter-branch`:

Primero tienes que crear un fichero y dentro poner el texto que quieres reemplazar:

```
$ echo "soy un dato sensible" > toReplace.txt
```

Luego utilizando BFG tienes que ejecutar esto:

```
$ git clone --mirror git://example.com/my-repo.git
$ java -jar bfg.jar --replace-text toReplace.txt  my-repo.git

$ cd my-repo.git

$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
$ git push
```

Lo que ocurrirá es que buscara "soy un dato sensible" y lo cambiara por * * * REMOVED * * *

Insisto: **Lee atentamente el enlace para ampliar la información ya que es una cosa sensible.**

Comment: Añadir un ejemplo a la respuesta sería genial :)